# Should I flag bad answers to questions which are closed already?

Tags: discussion, answers, flags, closed-questions

I haven't been flagging them since the question is closed already and will likely get deleted in the near future, so I figured why waste the moderators time flagging the answer? But there is that slight chance it might get reopened (very unlikely) and that answer would need to be removed.

Simple question: should I bother flagging an answer for deletion if the question has already been closed by users, or even a moderator?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use your best judgement: do *you* think the question should be re-opened? Do you see any reasonably chance that it will be? If so, removing poor answers (while perhaps voting to re-open the question) increases the chances of that.

If the question is poor, and the answers are poor, then there's no point in wasting any time trying to improve one without the other. Vote to delete the question (if you can), and let them all go down together.

Comment: Going off this, I understand that most questions closed as *exact duplicate* do not get deleted so that people can find that question via different methods. Would it make sense to flag bad answers in those questions, which may not ever get removed?

Comment: Good point, @animuson! I would be particularly concerned with "not an answer" answers in that scenario, since they just look ugly. On a related note that for duplicates that have *very good* answers posted prior to closing, you can request that a moderator merge with the original, thus giving them additional visibility - but since this will also merge any other answers, deleting them is useful for that reason also.